# Deserializing XML to object when they are not "shaped" the same?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, deserialization

I have an XML snippet like so:

```
<coverageCd>WEL
    <descriptorCd>SMIO
        <descriptorCdStartDate>01/01/2015</descriptorCdStartDate>
        <descriptorCdEndDate>12/31/9999</descriptorCdEndDate>
    </descriptorCd>
    <descriptorCd>AAE
        <descriptorCdStartDate>01/01/2015</descriptorCdStartDate>
        <descriptorCdEndDate>12/31/9999</descriptorCdEndDate>
    </descriptorCd>
</coverageCd>
```

I need to automagically translate this into the following class structure:

```
public class XmlCoverageCode
{
    public string CoverageCode { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<XmlDescriptor> Descriptors { get; set; }
}

public class XmlDescriptor
{
    public string DescriptorCode { get; set; }
    public string DescriptorCodeStartDate { get; set; }
    public string DescriptorCodeEndDate { get; set; }
}
```

...so the above XML snippet would translate to this:

```
var coverageCd = new XmlCoverageCode
{
    CoverageCode = "WEL",
    Descriptors =
        new List<XmlDescriptor>
        {
            new XmlDescriptor
            {
                DescriptorCode = "SMIO",
                DescriptorCodeStartDate = "01/01/2015",
                DescriptorCodeEndDate = "12/31/9999"
            },
            new XmlDescriptor
            {
                DescriptorCode = "AAE",
                DescriptorCodeStartDate = "01/01/2015",
                DescriptorCodeEndDate = "12/31/9999"
            }
        }
};
```

Naturally, I would prefer to use built-in mechanisms for doing this.  I just don't know if that's even possible.

Comment: Does LINQ code considered as built-in mechanism?

Comment: To a degree... I don't want to put logic into the deserialization, but rather define the model and where things should go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get classes from the XML, you can just copy your XML into clipboard and make *Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste XML As Classes* in Visual Studio. Then, after cleaning up of generated code, we get the following:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "coverageCd")]
public partial class XmlCoverageCode
{
    [XmlText]
    public string CoverageCode { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("descriptorCd")]
    public List<XmlDescriptor> Descriptors { get; set; }
}

public partial class XmlDescriptor
{
    [XmlText]
    public string DescriptorCode { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("descriptorCdStartDate")]
    public string DescriptorCodeStartDate { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("descriptorCdEndDate")]
    public string DescriptorCodeEndDate { get; set; }
}
```

This is actually the same, as you wrote in the question, but with the required attributes and changed `IEnumerable` to `List`, because `XmlSerializer` doesn't support the first one.

And the code snippet how to serialize/deserialize:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XmlCoverageCode));
var coverageCode = (XmlCoverageCode)serializer.Deserialize(xmlFileStream);
serializer.Serialize(xmlFileStream, coverageCode);
```

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you.  I will try this out

Answer (score 0):

You can use xsd command for converting xml to c# class
Save the xml in the file test.xml

- Run xsd.exe test.xml to generate a schema e.g. test.xsd
- Run xsd.exe    /c test.xsd to generate classes from the schema